# google.maps.places.PlacesService returns only one result

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, geolocation

I don't know, What is wrong with this code ?

When it executes, It returns only one search result.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'));
var request = {
    query: 'Electronic City'
};
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, function (results,status) {
    $scope.RecievedData = results;
});
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places" ></script>
```

Comment: what's wrong with a single result?

Comment: Dr.Molle Because user can choose one from multiple.

Comment: when there is one result, you have to accept it. the only thing you can rely on is that you don't get more than 20 results.

Comment: Ok got it.This was a noob question. I am removing my question.